# why the easy excel set cell style did not work

Tags: java, excel

I am using easy excel `api group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'easyexcel', version: '3.0.3'` to set the cell color, this is the `main.java` code:

```
public class AppStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkUserExcelRequest request = new SparkUserExcelRequest();
        request.setNickname("test");
        String writePathName = "/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/microservice/soa-zhuolian-org/";
        String fullPathName = writePathName  + "a.xlsx";
        if (!new File(writePathName).exists()) {
            new File(writePathName).mkdirs();
        }
        ExcelWriterBuilder writerBuilder = EasyExcel.write(fullPathName, SparkUserExcelRequest.class);
        writerBuilder.excelType(ExcelTypeEnum.XLSX);
        writerBuilder.registerWriteHandler(new CellStyleWriteHandler());
        ExcelWriter writer = writerBuilder.build();
        WriteSheet writeSheet = new WriteSheet();
        writeSheet.setSheetName("mark");
        writer.write(Arrays.asList(request), writeSheet);
        writer.finish();
    }
}
```

this is the class which change the cell color:

```
public class CellStyleWriteHandler extends AbstractCellStyleStrategy {

    @Override
    protected void setContentCellStyle(Cell cell, Head head, Integer relativeRowIndex) {
        Workbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
}
```

and this is the entity class:

```
@Data
@ExcelIgnoreUnannotated
public class SparkUserExcelRequest implements Serializable {

    @ExcelProperty("user name")
    private String nickname;
}
```

when I run this code, this cell color did not changed to light blue, why the cell color set failed? what should I do to fix this problem? I want the test cell color changed to blue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and the color did not change. Tried to downgrade your easyexcel version to 2.2.11 should fix this problem.You could add an issue to make sure is it a bug.

```
api group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'easyexcel', version: '2.2.11'
```